Dehalogenation of geminal dihalide
I found a reaction of a geminal dihalide with zinc in the book Organic chemistry by Clayden.
The reaction in question is :

I cannot find any reference online to the second reaction of Zn which seems to somehow get rid of the 2 chlorines. What is it called and what is the mechanism involved?

Please type in the text when you post your question.

This is called a Clemmensen reduction when done on a ketone and goes by a radical mechanism.

@Waylander, doesn't this reaction go through a mechanism similar to the Reformatsky enolate formation followed by protonation of the enolate?

@Waylander Huh, why wouldn't ketone group be reduced with Zn? @
GabrielAlx No it doesn't.

Well, I guess Zinc loses 2 of its electrons to form Zinc cation. The two bonds carbon forms with Cl results in it having a partial positive charge which is quite significant as there are two electronegative groups attached to it.  A homolytic bond cleavage takes place. The transition state would probably include: 1) The formation of Cl-Cl bond, 2) The homolytic cleavage of C-Cl bond and 3) The two carbon atoms gaining the two electrons lost by ZInc
